# connect 5v fan from voltage regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, fan

i have a 12v power supply and fan 5v 150mA and voltage regulator L7805 cv to reduce the voltage to 5volt  .
i need a circuit to just turn the fan on /off by switch .

can i connect the fan directly to vo & gnd from the L7805 ?

Comment: You'll need capacitors on the 7805 and in turning about a watt ((12-5) * .150) to heat, quite probably a heatsink too.  This is really not a very good idea, get a power supply and fan that match.

Comment: should i use free wheel diode in parallel in fan . or i dont have to ?

Comment: Use a switching regulator, not a 7805. They make little drop-in replacement modules if you look around on your preferred distributor's on-board power supply section.